# Zend Framework: How to delete a table row where multiple things are true?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

Normally, this would work for me:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$where = $db->quoteInto('id = ?', $id);
$db->delete('tablename', $where);
```

but I have to match two ids. So I don't really know how to structure it.

```
WHERE first_id = 'id1' AND second_id = 'id2'
```

So how do I do this with the Zend Framework?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To extend on Jason W's answer:

> Not exactly sure what the 3rd section
>   is saying

That means you can do this:

```
$db->delete('tablename', array(
    'first_id = ?' => $first_id,
    'second_id = ?' => $second_id
));
```

And the adapter will quote everything for you.

I don't feel like the documentation is very clear though.

Comment: Always check the API - the manual simply can't cover everything in enough detail

Comment: An API that forces you to reverse engineer it to do simple things is a crappy API.

Comment: Exactly @AlanStorm, to really use Zend Framework, you really have to dive into the source code. Makes for a steep and frustrating learning curve.

Answer (score 20):

From the [zend manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html#zend.db.adapter.write.delete) on delete():

> If you omit the second argument, the
>   result is that all rows in the
>   database table are deleted.
>
> If you provide an array of strings as
>   the second argument, these strings are
>   joined together as terms in an
>   expression separated by AND operators.
>
> If you provide an array of arrays as
>   the second argument, the the values
>   will be automatically quoted into the
>   keys. These will then be joined
>   together as terms, seperated by AND
>   operators.

Not exactly sure what the 3rd section is saying, but the 2nd implies that you can do:

```
$where = array();
$where[] = $db->quoteInto('first_id = ?', $first_id);
$where[] = $db->quoteInto('second_id = ?', $second_id);
$db->delete('tablename', $where);
```

Comment: That's the better way to do it!

Answer (score 2):

If you're in model which is extending class Zend_Db_Table_Abstract, you need to use different structure:

```
class Yourmodel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    protected $_name = 'tablename';
    protected $_primary = 'primarykey';
    public function remove($first_id, $second_id) {
        $where = array();
        $where[] = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('first_id = ?', $first_id);
        $where[] = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('second_id = ?', $second_id);
        $this->delete($where);
    }
}
```