# Zend_Db_Table: Delete multiple entries

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I wanted to delete some db entries and each of them has a unique ID. My current code looks so, taken from here: [Zend Framework: How to delete a table row where multiple things are true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845153/zend-framework-how-to-delete-a-table-row-where-multiple-things-are-true)

```
$where = array();
foreach ($IDs as $ID) {
   $where[] = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $ID);
}

$this->delete($where);
```

This is called inside the model class extends by Zend_Db_Table_Abstract.
The query looks now like that:

```
DELETE FROM `shouts` WHERE (id = '10') AND (id = '9') AND (id = '8')
```

That doesn't work of course because of the `AND`'s, this have to be `OR`'s to work correctly, but how could I get this work so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
$where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id IN (?)', $IDs);
$this->delete($where);
```