# Zend Framework delete rows doesn't work?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the same problem of this [Zend_Db_Table: Delete multiple entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549217/zend-db-table-delete-multiple-entries), but the code of fireeyedboy sames to not working. I haven't errors but the db entries still exist. What can i do?
My code in the model is identically in effect:

```
public function deleteUsers($usernames) //elimina più utenti passati con una stringa
{
    $where = array();
    foreach ($usernames as $username) {
    $where[] = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('username IN (?)', $username);
    }

    $this->delete($where);
}
```

Where $usernames is an array dinamically created by a multicheckbox selection. I assign the parameters to this array in this way in my controller:

```
$list=$this->getRequest()->getParam('utenti');
$this->_adminModel->deleteUsers($list);
$this->_redirector->gotoSimple('success',
                               'admin',
                                null);
```

For same reason my code go to the successAction but it not do the deleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit foreach loop. If $usernames is array of usernames, your deleteUsers method should look like this:

```
public function deleteUsers($usernames)
{
    $where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('username IN (?)', $usernames);
    $this->delete($where);
}
```

If not, please post output of var_dump($usernames).